# React: change order list when button clicked

Tags: reactjs, button

I am making my first app with Javascript and React and started with a page which views a shopping list. It gets the items from an api call.

If the user clicks on the button 'done' (or should I use an checkbox?) This product should go to the bottom of the list (and be grayed out with css but thats not the problem).

The problem is, I have no clue how to do this. Can anyone help me out a bit?

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
//import image from '../images/header.png';
//import Collapsible from './Collapsible';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        orders: []
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    localStorage.getItem('orders') && this.setState({
        orders: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orders')),
        isLoading: false
    })
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('orders')){
        this.fetchData();
    } else {
        console.log('Using  data from localstorage');
    }
}

fetchData() {
    fetch('http://localhost:54408/api/orders/all/15-03-2018')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(parsedJSON => parsedJSON.map(product => (
            {
                productname: `${product.ProductName}`,
                image: `${product.Image}`,
                quantity: `${product.Quantity}`,
                isconfirmed: `${product.IsConfirmed}`,
                orderid: `${product.OrderId}`
            }
        )))
        .then(orders => this.setState({
            orders,
            isLoading: false
        }))
        .catch(error => console.log('parsing failed', error))
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    localStorage.setItem('orders', JSON.stringify(nextState.orders));
    localStorage.setItem('ordersDate', Date.now());
}

render() {
    const {isLoading, orders} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <img src="/images/header.jpg"/>
                <h1>Boodschappenlijstje <button className="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Reload</button></h1>
            </header>
            <div className={`content ${isLoading ? 'is-loading' : ''}`}>
                <div className="panel">
                    {
                        !isLoading && orders.length > 0 ? orders.map(order => {
                        const {productname, image, quantity, orderid} = order;
                        return<div className="product" key={orderid}>
                            <div className="plaatjediv">
                                <img className="plaatje" src={image} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="productInfo">
                                <p>{productname}</p>
                                <p>Aantal: {quantity}</p>
                                <p>ID: {orderid}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="bdone">
                                <button className="btn btn-sm btn-default btndone">Done</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }) : null
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="loader">
                    <div className="icon"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
 export default App;
```

Comment: One simple approach is: add `.sort` just before your `orders.map`. Then you'll have `orders.sort(yourCustomSortFunction).map(...)`. Once the orders are clicked you have to have a callback in which you change in order to make it move to the end of the array.
To make your component clearer, try to modularize more this component. Instead of having `!isLoading && orders.length > 0 ? orders.map...` you could have a component which is a list of orders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and tip to make a component for my productlist that will make my code clearer for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using this :

```
this.handleDoneAction = event = > {
    let itemIndex = event.target.getAttribute("data-itemIndex");
    let prevOrders = [...this.state.orders];
    var itemToMoveAtLast = prevOrders.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    var updatedOrderList = prevOrders.concat(itemToMoveAtLast);
    this.setState({order: updatedOrderList})

}
```

I have attach an event handler on the button `handleDoneAction`.

```
<button className="btn btn-sm btn-default btndone" data-itemIndex={index} onClick={this.handleDoneAction}>Done</button>
```

the attribute data-itemIndex is the index of the object in orders array.

And your map function will be like this:

```
orders.map((order, index) => { 
    //content
})
```

ANd for the different style effects on the done products, I will suggest you to use different array for all done products.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This works. Only thing is if you click the button the page automatically scrolls down, but I want to stay at the top of the page.
I was thinking to add a class to the div when the button is clicked but your suggestion of an extra array is also not a bad idea. Like remove the clicked product from the orders array and add it to an other array?